# Printing More than One Page with a Loop From DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a code am working that prints a sales report from a DataGridView. The Code prints well but can only print one page when the Value of the control Variable I goes out of the printable area. I really Need your help. Below is the code.

```
            Dim fntAddress As New Font("Comic Sans MS", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim fntHeader As New Font("Calibri", 20, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim fntBodyText As New Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim fntHeaderText As New Font("Calibri", 13, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim strTotalSale = txtTotal.Text

        e.Graphics.DrawString("SFC POINT OF SALE AND INVENTORY MANAGEMENT", fntHeader, Brushes.Black, 100, 0)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("GENERATED SALES REPORT", New Font("Calibri", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 250, 30)

        Dim strDateString As String = ""
        If mtbStartDate.Text = "  /  /" Or mtbEndDate.Text = "  /  /" Then
            strDateString = ""
        ElseIf mtbStartDate.Text = mtbEndDate.Text Then
            strDateString = "Report For Date Of : " & mtbStartDate.Text
        ElseIf mtbStartDate.Text <> mtbEndDate.Text Then
            strDateString = "Report For Dates Of : " & mtbStartDate.Text & " - " & mtbEndDate.Text
        End If

        e.Graphics.DrawString(strDateString, New Font("Courier New", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 5, 70)

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(5, 100, 770, 35))
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Item Barcode", fntHeaderText, Brushes.Black, 10, 107)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Item Name", fntHeaderText, Brushes.Black, 160, 107)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Quantity", fntHeaderText, Brushes.Black, 360, 107)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Unit Cost", fntHeaderText, Brushes.Black, 450, 107)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Sub Total", fntHeaderText, Brushes.Black, 560, 107)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Date of Sale", fntHeaderText, Brushes.Black, 660, 107)

        Dim RowCount As Integer = dgvSales.Rows.Count - 1
        Static i As Integer = 139
        Dim x1 = 10
        Dim x2 = 700
        Dim y1 = 155
        Dim n As Integer = 0


        While n < RowCount
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(5, i - 5, 770, 35))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvSales.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value, fntBodyText, Brushes.Black, 16, i)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvSales.Rows(n).Cells(1).Value, fntBodyText, Brushes.Black, 160, i)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvSales.Rows(n).Cells(2).Value, fntBodyText, Brushes.Black, 360, i)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvSales.Rows(n).Cells(3).Value, fntBodyText, Brushes.Black, 450, i)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvSales.Rows(n).Cells(4).Value, fntBodyText, Brushes.Black, 560, i)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvSales.Rows(n).Cells(5).Value, fntBodyText, Brushes.Black, 660, i)
            i = i + 35
            n = n + 1
        End While
        e.HasMorePages = False
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 150, 100, 150, i - 5)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 350, 100, 350, i - 5)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 440, 100, 440, i - 5)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 550, 100, 550, i - 5)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 650, 100, 650, i - 5)

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(340, i + 40, 174, 50))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(341, i + 41, 172, 48))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(342, i + 42, 170, 46))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(343, i + 43, 168, 44))
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Sales.", New Font("Times New Roman (Headings CS)", 22, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 341, i + 47)

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(525, i + 40, 250, 50))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(526, i + 41, 248, 48))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(527, i + 42, 246, 46))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(528, i + 43, 244, 44))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(strTotalSale, New Font("Times New Roman (Headings CS)", 23, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 538, i + 47)
```

Comment: Static i As Integer = 139 .. what is that for ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I haven't written one line of VB code in my life, but the printing mechanism at a glance seems extremely similar to the Java Printing API.

You have to mark the fact that the document you're printing has more pages yourself, using `e.hasMorePages = True`.

Here is a working example:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/139447-help-with-hasmorepages-please/

Take into consideration the fact that you must always know the place you left off on the former page. Here is another, more realistic example: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/128639-ehasmorepages-and-logic-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you understand that it could be complex because you have to calculate fontheight, papersize height, etc.

In this case, consider that there would be a fixed setting

```
Dim nMaxLine as Integer = 30 ' ----------> lines count per page
Dim x as Integer
Dim n as Integer 

For x = 0 to datagridview.rows.count - 1
  ' ..
  e.Graphics.DrawString( ... )
  ' ..
  n += 1
  If n > nMaxLine Then
    e.hasMorePages = True
    n = 0
  End If
Next
```